# How to move between 2 very different directories in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, navigation, cp

When I move files with a GUI file manager, I navigate to the source and destination directory in 2 different windows, and then drag and drop. Is there a way to do this in BASH (move a file to a directory, but be able to navigate to the new directory rather than needing to know the full path right away to put in the argument)

I know how to use commands like mv, and cp, but both of these take one full path as the argument, and I want to be able to navigate to the new destination separate from navigating to the source file... if that makes sense

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you want to achieve. You can use two different terminal windows(or tabs) , or VTs if you are in console mode. Then you can move and/or copy files with `mv` and `cp` as you said, and connect to a directory with `cd` and list the files with `ls`.

Comment: You have a current directory and you navigate using .. as previous directory and tab to complete. Eg mv test* ../../otherdir/private/ will move all files whose names start with test to the private directory of the otherdir directory of the second parent of the source.

Comment: You can use the Tab key to complete paths and "navigate" directories while building the arguments to `cp` and `mv`. For example: type `cp /ho` and press the Tab key.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood, but you want a console file manager so you could navigate your folders in two panels. You could try with [Midnight commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org).

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Comment: Great answer. this is what i do now, but i really want to try to move into just using the terminal. I feel like knowledge like this will be especially handy when im ssh'd onto machines

Answer (score 2):

There are two commands to allow you to easily move back and forth between directories:

```
pushd
popd
```

For an example, navigate to the first directory with cd:

`cd /home/aperson/more/path/to/a/very/long/and/annoying/to/type/`

Then use pushd to move to the other directory:

`pushd  /home/aperson/more/path/to/a/different/very/long/and/annoying/to/type/`

Now when you call `popd` again you will be back in the first directory.

This just helps with the navigation though, you will still need to do your `mv` or `cp` separately.

Depending on how much you need to do it may be worth assigning your paths to variables so you don't have to type the full path out:

```
DIR1="/home/aperson/a/very/long/and/annoying/to/type/"
DIR2="/home/aperson/a/different/very/long/and/annoying/to/type/"
```

Now you can use `$DIR1` and `$DIR2` to refer to the directories i.e.

```
cp somestuff.stuff $DIR1
cd $DIR1
mv somestuff.stuff $DIR2
cd $DIR2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly navigation, but I am guessing what you're looking for is TAB AUTO COMPLETION.

This will allow you to get the full part of any directory without having to know it.

[Here's a great tutorial for this](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why nobody mentioned two easy ways to achieve what op asks.

First way:

```
cd -  #goes back to previous directory
```

Second way:

```
cd $OLDPWD
```

For more info check out following link https://superuser.com/questions/113219/go-back-to-previous-directory-in-shell

EDIT: I found really a nice `.bashrc` function in following link by Adam Katz which is a must for easy navigation in bash shell: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/quick-directory-navigation-in-the-terminal

I tried it, it works well.

Comment: +1 for `$OLDPWD` in particular

Comment: 'cd --' does NOT take you back two levels. '--' is a generic GNU convention to indicate that there are no further options, so 'cd --' is interpreted exactly as 'cd' (without any options), which takes you to your home directory.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.  I don't know how I reached that misconception. I should have been cautious before posting an anwer. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tab feature that comes with ubuntu's terminal (`ctrl + shift + t`).
This way you could search for your destination directory in the second tab using the `cd` and `ls` commands. then once in the desired directory you could use the `pwd` command (print working directory) to get the full path to said directory. Once you have that, copy and paste the path over to your first terminal tab where you are executing your `cp` or `mv` command.

[image]

If you are not familiar with `cd` and `ls`, here is a great little tutorial for some of the basic bash commands.

[The Command Line Crash Course](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

I hope this is of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, that's more akin to the GUI 'cut and paste' idea.

```
cd /long/path/to/wherever/the/file/is/now
mv file_to_move /tmp/
cd /destination/directory/somewhere/else/
mv /tmp/file_to_move ./
```

But really, it involves much more typing than a simple single  `cp <source> <destination>`

Answer (score 0):

#### Autojump with Tab completions

This doesn't exactly answer your question, BUT if you've been to that particular folder before, you can simply use the autojump command/program to allow you to quickly jump between folders.

`j Pictures` and i'm in the pictures folder

`j AnotherFolder` and then instantly, I am transported to that folder.

Best part of about autojump is that it respects tab completions, and cycles through folders with the similar names.